# explode function from a form field

Tags: php, forms, text, explode

I have an HTML form where the user is asked to paste some code :

```
<!-- Facebook Badge START -->

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alex.gk" target="_TOP" style="font-family: &quot;lucida grande&quot;,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #3B5998; text-decoration: none;" title="Alex Gk">Alex Gk</a>

<span style="font-family: &quot;lucida grande&quot;,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #555555; text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/badges/" target="_TOP" style="font-family: &quot;lucida grande&quot;,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; color: #3B5998; text-decoration: none;" title="&#x394;&#3b7;&#x3bc;&#x3b9;&#x3bf;&#x3c5;&#x3c1;&#x3b3;&#x3ae;&#x3c3;&#x3c4;&#x3b5; &#x3c4;&#x3bf; &#x3b4;&#x3b9;&#x3ba;&#x3cc; &#x3c3;&#x3b1;&#x3c2; &#x3b4;&#x3b9;&#x3b1;&#x3ba;&#x3c1;&#x3b9;&#x3c4;&#x3b9;&#x3ba;&#x3cc;!">Δημιουργήστε το δικό σας διακριτικό</a><br/>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alex.gk" target="_TOP" title="Alex G">
    <img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/1565383.3437.1745257502.png" style="border:0px;" />
</a>

 <!-- Facebook Badge END -->
```

What I want in PHP is to keep only the below part so as the user pastes the whole code 
but after submitting the form it keeps only the below part .

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alex.gk" target="_TOP" title="AlexG">
    <img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/1383.3437.1745257502.png" style="border:0px;" />
</a>
```

Comment: you can use explode() and will return array however if you know if the first or send word is bold in Alex Gk | Δημιουργήστε το δικό σας διακριτικό you can do as $str = 'Alex Gk | Δημιουργήστε το δικό σας διακριτικό'; $arr = explode("|",$str); now $arr[0] and $arr[1] will contain the strings and if you know which is bold you can use that array index.

Comment: I dont see any **bold** part in the posted code. If the bold parts comes from your user, why not posting the relevant code.

Comment: Is this pasted html always structured this way? if so, you could use something like the domdocument load html function and always grab the 3rd anchor. http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `strip_tags()`?

`$text = strip_tags($text, '<b><strong');`

Comment: thanks for your answer. What i want is to keep only this part:<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alex.gk" target="_TOP" title="Alex Gk">
    <img src="https://badge.facebook.com/badge/1505265383.3437.1745257502.png" style="border:0px;" />
</a> it's not bold.my mistake